# Can files be modified when freezed in executable?

Tags: python, file

I am almost up to finish my little game project in PyQt and i am going to freeze it to exe with cx_Freeze. There is a Leaderboard system, it uses text files, arranges scores with text files, shows them etc.

However, If i freeze the whole package to executable, will they still be accessible with Python's file system?

```
with open("Leaderboard.txt") as file:
     file.write(str(sometext))
```

Would this code change the file? or it give the error about file type.

If the second statement is true, then how can i do it? should i use installer that will put all the data in registry files? and would i need to specify the whole path to registry then?

This is my [cx_freeze setup.py file](https://github.com/ShellRox/Questions-and-Problems/blob/master/setup.py).

Comment: The most important thing here is, if the executable is a single file or not. While `cx_freeze` does not able to freeze all files into one single executable, you can use relative paths for file access. Files in the executable folder should be writable for you.

Comment: Everything is contained in single file, by my research i have found that including files in executable can be done with this: `includefiles = ['Leaderboard.txt', 'Somefile.txt']`, do i need to specify the full path here? even if they are in the same folder?

Comment: You my have misunderstood me, `cx_freeze` is not able to create single-file executables. Do you have a folder with an exe and some files in it after building?

Comment: Although i am working on OSX now i am trying to convert it to exe for specific usage, But i haven't tried it yet, haven't completed application and thinking if i need to add something inside, sorry for misunderstanding though i just started using cx_freeze, I have a folder that has all the files inside, do i need to change something in   `includefiles = ['Leaderboard.txt', 'Somefile.txt']` ?

Comment: No, should be fine. But make a first build please, test the result and report further issues.

Comment: I'm sorry for being annoying, should the script look relative to this? : https://github.com/ShellRox/Questions-and-Problems/blob/master/setup.py

Comment: Asking questions is OK :). I remember back when I've tried to create my first executable form Python code, that wasn't easy at all... I've crated a fork of your repo and I'll made a pull request with some edits in a minute. Keep going asking if there are questions left!

Comment: Ok, pull request is out. Next thing would be to add some metadata (author, version, copyright ect.) and a nice icon :). See http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io for this.

Comment: Thanks a lot, how do i add the icon and copyright? i would add copyright in application itself, but don't know about icon. I have only found adding it with `--icon icon`

Comment: Ok, another pull request is out. Sorry, I can't figure out how to set copyright in cx_freeze :/. Does the executable work?

Comment: Uh, sorry, I mean new commit in my initial pull request...

Comment: Yes it did show up, thanks! i am gonna try it out and give the information.

Comment: @linusg sorry for responding lately, i first got this error: `ImportError: No module named 'PyQt4.uic.port_v3.proxy_base'` then tried removing it from packages, only putting resources file inside it, and now i got this error: `error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'QtDesigner.framework/Versions/4/QtDesigner'
`

Comment: If you don't need `PyQt4.uic`, try to exclude it explicit.

Comment: i appended it to excludes, but it gave me this: `ImportError: No module named 'PyQt4.uic'`. @linusg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111991/discussion-between-shellrox-and-linusg).